# How to append a table to another where the data being appended is not already in the appended table?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in Ms Access that I want to append namely tblMaster and tblNew. The problem is some of the data in tblNew is already in tblMaster. How can I append tblNew to tblMaster and exclude the data that is already in tblMaster?

Comment: Are the data exactly the same? Is there a primary key?

Comment: To expand on what @Brad has stated, does `tblMaster` have a foreign key that exists in `tblNew`?

Comment: There is no primary key in the tblMaster. I wasn't the one who created this database and it is poorly normalized. I'm asked to append the tblNew data without creating duplicate of what already exist in tblMaster.

Comment: What fields to you use to tell if the data is duplicate vs. new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a specific unique key field would most certainly be easiest - but you can still accomplish it by simply using a combination fields as the unique key (essentially creating your own).

You can then do the update by linking the new table to the old table, on the fields that you designate should make up the unique key.

Suppose you have an "Employees" table and an "Employees New" table.  You want the employee's name and badge number to form the unique key.  This would be the SQL to add in any records that do not exist in the old employee table.

```
INSERT INTO [Employees]
     ( FIELD1, 
       EMPLOYEENAME, 
       BADGENUMBER, 
       FIELD2, 
       FIELD3, 
       FIELD4 )
SELECT NEW.FIELD1, 
       NEW.EMPLOYEENAME, 
       NEW.BADGENUMBER, 
       NEW.FIELD2, 
       NEW.FIELD3, 
       NEW.FIELD4
  FROM [Employees New] AS NEW 
       LEFT JOIN [Employees] AS OLD 
                 ON (NEW.EMPLOYEENAME = OLD.EMPLOYEENAME) AND 
                    (NEW.BADGENUMBER = OLD.BADGENUMBER)
 WHERE (OLD.EMPLOYEENAME Is Null);
```

This works by linking the "Employees" table with the "Employees New" using the fields determined to make up a primary key.   It limits the results to show only those records where the new employee is not in the old employee table already.

The next decision would be deciding if you want to update existing records in the Employee table with the values in the new table.  If so, you'd use an approach like this.

```
UPDATE [Employees] AS OLD 
       INNER JOIN [Employees New] AS NEW 
                  ON (OLD.BADGENUMBER = NEW.BADGENUMBER) AND 
                     (OLD.EMPLOYEENAME = NEW.EMPLOYEENAME) 
   SET OLD.Field1 = NEW.Field1,
       OLD.Field2 = NEW.Field2,
       OLD.Field3 = NEW.Field3,
       OLD.Field4 = NEW.Field4;
```

This works by joining both the "Employees" and "Employees New" table, showing only records in both tables where the unique key fields match.  We then update all fields.

Hopefully that puts you in the right direction.